# C++ to C code conversion, is it equivalent?

Tags: c++, c

I had to convert a C++ program to C, which has been done. The question is whether the codes presented are equivalent and whether I missed anything.

Both codes presented are complete and should compile. Both give the same answers when run, too. But I am new to C++ and I don't know if I missed something in my conversion that might be important.

One more question, in the C++ code, int x and int y were declared as global, I don't have, and don't think I need anything analogous to that, but I don't really know what they are doing. Guidance?

#### C++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

// a point on the integer grid

struct Point
{
  // constructor
  Point()
  {
    x = y = 0;
  }

  // add point componentwise
  void add(const Point &p)
  {
    x += p.x;
    y += p.y;
  }

  // print to standard output
  void print() const
  {
    std::cout << "[" << x << "," << y << "]" << std::endl;
  }

  // data
  int x, y;
};

int main()
{
  const int N = 200;
  Point *A = new Point[N], sum;

  for (int i=0; i < N; ++i) {
    sum.print();
    A[i].x = i; A[i].y = -i;
    sum.add(A[i]);
  }
  sum.print();

  delete [] A;
}
```

#### C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct //constructor
{
     int x;
     int y;
} Point;

void add(const Point * p, Point * sum)
{
    (*sum).x += (*p).x;
    (*sum).y += (*p).y;

}

void print(const int x, const int y)
{
    printf("[%d,%d]\n", x, y);
}

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    const int N = 200;


   Point *A = malloc(N*sizeof(Point)), sum;
   if(!A)
        {
        printf(stderr, "malloc() failed to allocate memory!");
        abort();
        }

   sum.x =0;
   sum.y = 0;

    for (i = 0; i <N; i++)
    {
    print (sum.x, sum.y);
        A[i].x = i; A[i].y = -i;
     add(&A[i], &sum);
    }
    print(sum.x, sum.y);

    free(A);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: In C++ you could create a class called `Point` instead of using a `struct`

Comment: I should clarify that I didn't write the C++ code, only the C one.

Comment: Nearly. You need `if(!A) {printf(stderr, "malloc() failed to allocate memory!"); abort();}` in the C version after `malloc`. (Replace with whatever new-failure gives) Then they will be.

Comment: @pzaenger: In C++, there is only one difference between using `struct` and `class`: The default access-specifier. And for a case like this, where no access-protection is wanted, `class` would be inappropriate. (BTW: I would leave out the dtor as well!) Also, I'm assuming C99 or newer.

Comment: Nice catch. I knew I was forgetting something.

Comment: For your consideration, C uses prefixes where C++ uses namespaces/classes. None of your translated functions has a proper prefix.

Comment: The C++ version is consistently indented. The declaration of the loop counter outside of the loop shouldn't be necessary in C. That said, there are no global `x` and `y` in the C++ version that you asked about...

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: Neither are there global variables in the C++-version...

Comment: Does C have namespaces? If so you may use those to group the functions associated with struct Point.  Beyond that the best test for equivalence IMHO is if it gives the same output for the same input. Generate a massive test data and compare!

Comment: `(*p).` That looks clumsy. Better use the arrow-operator: `p->`  Dito `&A[i]`: Better `A+i`

Comment: @Deduplicator Could you elaborate on the proper prefix or give me an example? I'm a bit new to this.

Re: UlrichEckhard Noted. Going to fix the indentation but I wanted to find out first if everything was fine otherwise. Thanks! 

For the global x and y I thought the x and y declared outside of main were global? I didn't notice them being used anywhere, so I'm at a loss as to what they were for?

Comment: Neither function declares any global variables, only types and functions. And you decide for each type (or a whole library), which prefix you want. The important part is that it schould be consistent. Anyway, please mind the difference between *declare* and *define*.

Comment: you may add missing `const`. And `(*sum).x` is equivalent to `sum->x`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about doing a [codereview.SE].

Comment: Well, if you add the `const` to `add`, you might also pass the point by `const Point*` to `print`.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Thanks, this is very educational. Should I declare the functions in the C program? it seems redundant (If I understand correctly, I defined all the functions I use, but I didn't declare them since I'm not making header files or similar).

Comment: @Murbly you only have to declare functions if you use them before they are defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fairly equivalent functionally (aside from the constructor issue, see below). But for some reason it contains a number of inconsistencies and "illogical" stylistic decisions.

- The "standard" approach to approximate a C++ method by a C function is to implement the C++ implicit `this` parameter through an explicit parameter. That would make your `add` function look as follows

  ```
  void add(Point *this, const Point *p)
  {
    this->x += p->x;
    this->y += p->y;
  }
  ```

  Note that in C++ version you could also use the `this->x` syntax on the left-hand side (instead of just `x`), which would only emphasize the similarity. Obviously, my version above is the same as yours, but arranged in what I believe is more "traditional" fashion.
- You forgot to define a "constructor" for your `Point` in C version of the code. In C++ code your `Point` objects begin their lives initialized to zero. In C code these objects begin their lives with garbage in `x` and `y`. Later you assign definitive values to `x` and `y`, which makes the non-initialization issue non-consequential, but still it is there.

  Of course, if you decide to implement a "constructor" function, you will have to call it manually for each array element, while in C++ it is called automatically for you.
- For some reason you decided to "disassemble" the object into `x` and `y` parameters for `print` function. Why? Again, the same approach with an explicit `this` parameter can be used for `print` and it would look as follows

  ```
  void print(const Point *this)
  {
    printf("[%d,%d]\n", this->x, this->y);
  }
  ```

  In your current version

  ```
  void print(const int x, const int y)
  ```

  `const` qualifiers applied to parameters achieve virtually nothing useful and do not promote equivalence to the C++ version (i.e. these `const` qualifiers are not equivalent to that trailing `const` in the C++ version).

  But, in any case, these are purely stylistic suggestions.
- Note also that in C++ language

  ```
  const int N = 200;
  ```

  defines a *constant*, while in C language it does not define a constant. In C it defines what essentially is a "non-modifiable variable". But this is completely non-consequential for your code, since your code does not care whether `N` is a constant or not. (I don't know whether you care about this sort of pedantic equivalence.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments!

I'm new to coding and I suppose I'm more comfortable with the syntax I used than with the ->. That said, changed it.

Good point on print

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the level of 'equivalency' you're looking for. In the C version you don't have a function equivalent to the Point constructor and you avoid the default initialization on the array of points, your C print function operates on `int`s instead of a Point object, and I see some `const` mismatches such as the fact that your C `add` function takes a pointer to non-const `Point` on the right hand side while the C++ version takes a reference to const `Point`.

Comment: Good point. Added a constructor function to initialize the Point values to 0 after the malloc call.

I didn't think it mattered since I give the structs values right away (other than new, not initializing that makes the output incorrect), but it should certainly be there. Thanks